# how know where is the error?

Tags: django, django-admin

im using a django app (django adzone), well, but im trying to add banners, and django zone tell me " please fix the errors" , but nothing more, i cant see where are the errors.

any idea how ill know ?

## EDITED

There's not trace about the error or something like that, is just a django admin message
see the images
[image]

thanks

Comment: When does it tell you to "please fix the errors"?

Comment: i generally make a grep in the folder of the app, something like: grep -inr "please fix the errors"

Comment: @awithrow if im adding a new banner, i got: Please correct the error below

Comment: If it says "Please correct the error below", logic would suggest the error below is displayed. It might be hard for you to understand, but if you cut and paste in the entire error we will be able to help you.

Comment: @Jordan there's not more error :(, just this

Comment: Im installed adzone in my local machine, a new project with just this app and the error is the same...

Comment: OK, i know where is the error. There's another field named "Advertiser", but Chrome dont display this field, i dont know why. sorry i think there is not error, just a Chrome "bug", i think.

FF,Opera, IE are showing the complete form.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i know where is the error.

There's another field named "Advertiser", but Chrome dont display this field, i dont know why. sorry i think there is not error, just a Chrome "bug".

FF,Opera, IE are showing the complete form.

Thanks

Comment: Go ahead and mark this as the answer so people know this has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Then your best shot is to install ipdb (easy_install ipdb) then drop these lines in at the end of the is_valid method (and if not create it):

import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()

Save your form again, then go to the router. You'll have access to a shell where you can inspect several suspects like:

- self.data
- self.errors

Answer (score 0):

Been there, seen that!

It's not a chrome bug it's the Ad blocker blocking the input!

You can:
Deactivate the Ad blocker or rename the field (Advertise)

Cheers